# Padding around tick labels

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm doing a bar chart.

```
sns_plot = sns.barplot(years, yields, ax=axes[0, 0])
sns_plot.set_xticklabels(years, rotation=90)
sns_plot.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)
```

But the text is too bunched up. I.e. need separation between the labels. How can I do this? The `pad=10` seems to push the labels from the axis rather then separate labels.

After the labels are vertical (90 deg), they are still a bit bunched up. I guess finding the right lever to pull...

Comment: You should be able to rotate the labels so that they do not look as cluttered.

Comment: It's a bit like asking for a larger separation between house numbers. For that you would either need a longer street or less houses.

Comment: ... or smaller houses.

Comment: Smaller house*numbers*  would work.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data:**

```
In [1]:
import numpy as np
import re

x = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Cras nibh turpis, ullamcorper ac lectus vel, 
aliquet consectetur odio. Cras vel scelerisque tortor. 
Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. 
Proin id dignissim ante, a dictum ipsum. Fusce at lacus ac purus 
pulvinar dignissim eget a quam. Sed quis mollis ligula, sed 
ullamcorper velit. Curabitur vel congue metus. Ut placerat 
ipsum non leo posuere, non vestibulum eros posuere. 
Donec eu viverra augue, sit amet tempus ex. Vivamus 
sit amet tempus ipsum. Fusce consequat, augue a mollis 
hendrerit, quam neque dapibus ligula, vitae blandit ipsum 
lorem eu mauris. """
x = pd.Series(x.split(' '))
x = x.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\W+', '', x))
y = np.random.randn(x.shape[0])

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': x, 'Y': y})
df.head()


Out [1]:
    X   Y
0   Lorem   -0.562246
1   ipsum   1.085094
2   dolor   1.044887
3   sit     -1.424002
4   amet    -0.87682
```

**Test plot:**

```
In [2]:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9, 6))
ax.plot(df.X, df.Y, 'ks')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

Out [2]:
```

So to summarize comments to the original post, there are multiple ways to remove cluttered ticklabels you have multiple options:

1) Smaller label text: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=6)`
[image]

2) Less labels:

```py
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

[image]

3) Longer Axis: `fig.set_size_inches((15, 4))`
[image]
And so on...